# How do you paint multiple different textures using the RGBA channels?

Tags: texturing

This video by Blender Guru outlines that it is possible to paint separate textures on the base layer, red, green, blue and alpha channels. However, he does not cover how to do this in the video.

https://youtu.be/1aNnERnHRZg?t=477

How do I do this?

Edit: Specifically, I want to know how the shaders are configured to allow me to paint like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple node setup which will work

> **Click on the images to expand them in size so that you can see the node structure.**

**RESULT**

[image]

[image]
[image]

The way I have structured the shader to work is through adding one texture on top of the other, until all the textures have been applied.

**Some additional thoughts I had on this shader setup:**

I believe an unlimited amount of textures could theoretically be applied with this method. With a single image, you can apply the base albedo, texture on the red channel, texture on the green channel, texture on the blue channel, and texture on the alpha channel - so 5 textures. To add more than 5 textures, just add another image to paint on, and then add on the textures with the mix shader node.

Also, different shaders could be used to render each texture. I'm pretty sure you could do that but I could be wrong.

Thank you to @NatureK for the initial schema for this.

Answer (score 2):

Creat the nodes as below,the main idea is use the number of texture RGBA to decide which BSDF should be render."fac" is the texture.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have updated the post. Thank you for letting me know it needed more clarity.

Comment: I managed to make a shader setup which can use 5 textures based on your work. I'll put it up in a minute. I couldn't have done it without your help. Thank you~

Comment: As I want to make it perfect,I found out what Guru do is not the best,because to combine RGBA is a little complex, you can only use different value of R to set your node, and it's quite easy to extend the texture quantity.

Comment: i noticed the exact same when i created my own! interesting that we came to the same conclusion